# set FragmentGridPagerAdapter starting row

Tags: android-adapter, wear-os

I'm using a `GridViewPager` and a `FragmentGridPagerAdapter` in my Android Wear application but it always start at the first item. Do you have any idea how I can make it start at another row ?

The problem is that when you use `setCurrentItem` just avec the `setAdapter` you get a NullpointerException because the grid hasn't been populated yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not proud of it but here's a solution :

```
Runnable dirtyHack = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          gridViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, 1);
     }
};
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(dirtyHack, 100);
```

The idea came from the github: https://github.com/kurtisnelson/wearatron/blob/4835a19d90eb484ca499831ed343b4279a3dd41b/wear/src/main/java/com/thisisnotajoke/wearatron/LockitronActivity.java